# eXist Native XML database

Tags: wordpress, xml, tei

I have a simple Wordpress site with phpMyAdmin panel for creating a database. The database which I have to use is so called native XML db eXist-DB and I don't know how to connect it to my website or how to import it. Is there any software or may be plugin to do this?

Comment: Nikki, I'm curious as to whether you got the answer to this in such a fashion that you were able to connect existDB to WordPress. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Phpmyadmin to connect to eXist. It's a completely different Technology than mySQL and mariaDB.  Don't use eXist if you are beginner. You'd need to learn an absurdly complex technology stack that almost nobody else uses. ([Read "Recent News"](http://www.cafeconleche.org/) section how one Java/XML Expert wrestled with eXist in 2010. I doubt it has become much easier).

If you must:

Read the docs on http://exist-db.org/. Download eXist. Ask a Java Programmer how to  setup the tooling infrastructure (JRE/JDK, Maven, Tomcat/Jetty.... whatever else) and connect to the database.

If your website is simple, maybe your legacy data stored in eXist is simple too. Just let an expert extract the data in a one-off task, and store the data as CSV file, perhaps. Then forget about eXist.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The main problem is that I am a humanitarian and I have to operate with xml xsl and xquery and for this purposes Exist-Db is the one that I have to use. I will try to follow your tips. Thank you once again